# Как построить график Seaborn с итоговыми суммами по месяцам?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу, у меня есть такой **Датафрейм**:

| ДАТА | ИМЯ | ИТОГ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-28 | Света | 3250 |
| 2021-06-01 | Катя | 2560 |
| 2021-06-05 | Наташа | 2589 |
| 2021-07-15 | Ольга | 15668 |
| 2021-07-24 | Андрей | 5580 |
| 2022-01-08 | Влад | 6580 |
| 2022-01-15 | Артем | 9500 |

У меня не получается построить информативный график, что бы по оси **У** были итоговые суммы за каждый месяц, а по **X** были эти самые даты из таблицы сгруппированные по месяцам.

Я пытался использовать *.groupby()*, делал индексацию по колонке *"ДАТА"*, но в итоге не получается получить информативный график, либо сталкиваюсь с ошибками. К слову графики я пытался стоить *.displot() или .countplot()*, может быть они не подходят для этих задач?

Подскажите какие методы можно использовать. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по представленным датам за каждый месяц у одного человека только одна запись, в этом случае группировка вообще не нужна:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import seaborn as sns

data = StringIO('''
ДАТА    ИМЯ ИТОГ
2021-05-28  Света   3250
2021-06-01  Катя    2560
2021-06-05  Наташа  2589
2021-07-15  Ольга   15668
2021-07-24  Андрей  5580
2022-01-08  Влад    6580
2022-01-15  Артем   9500
''')

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep='\s+')
df['ГОД-МЕСЯЦ'] = df['ДАТА'].str.slice(0, 7)
sns.barplot(x='ГОД-МЕСЯЦ', y='ИТОГ', hue='ИМЯ', data=df);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если людей отдельно показывать не нужно, то нарисовать такое ещё проще, хотя простой `matplotlib` не так красив, как `seaborn`:

```py
df.groupby('ГОД-МЕСЯЦ')['ИТОГ'].sum().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!
Но кстати да, я привел не совсем точный пример оригинального датафрейма, на самом же деле действительно в одном месяце некоторые люди могут повторять по несколько раз. В этом случае как поменяется код, который вы прислали?

Comment: И еще дополню , в целом отображать имена на графике не требуется - их слишком много, график становится невозможно читать. Главное чтобы были все месяца и итоговая сумма за заказы по этим месяцам.

Comment: То есть нужно складывать итого всех людей в одном месяце, так?

Comment: Да, получается что так

Comment: Ну тогда смотрите дополнение к ответу

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но почему-то это всё равно приводит к тому, что у меня строится график для каждого дня всех месяцев и годов.. Мне помогла функция .resample(), я написал следующий код > newdf = df.set_index('ДАТА').resample('M')["ИТОГ"].sum() , после чего получилось построить график, но только с помощью matplotlib , как сделать так, что бы воспользоваться Seaborn, пока не могу понять

Comment: А вы заметили, что я делаю колонку `df['ГОД-МЕСЯЦ'] = df['ДАТА'].str.slice(0, 7)` и строю график уже по ней? Но это сработает только если дата именно в формате `год-месяц-день` и именно в виде строки. А что касается `seaborn` - возможно, вам нужно сделать `reset_index`, наверное дата у вас находится в индексе.

Comment: Да, вы правы, я не заметил, тогда все получилось)